# how to change code to get image from folder?

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I'm making a weather app for a school project.

To get the weather icon I have now this code:

```
function getWeather (city){

$.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&appid=50bc264b6f0b99a1cfe346238e1e9383", {}, function(data){


    var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon;
    var iconurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";

    TweenLite.from("#weer" , 4 , {X: -360} );           

    $("#desc").html('Sky: ' + data.weather[0].description);
    $("#temp ").html(data.main.temp + '  °F');
    $("#wind").html(data.wind.speed + '  KM/H');
    $("#stad").html(data.name);
    $("#icon").html("<img src='" + iconurl + "' alt='Icon depicting current weather'>");



    TweenMax.from("#weather" , 2 , {x: -1000}  );

    })

}
```

Now I want to change it to get the icons from the project folder on my pc and not from the URL.
Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: in that case you need a webserver on your PC so you can point the code to the URL of your own files instead of the other site. The image source must always be a valid URL of some sort. So if you haven't got a webserver already, you'll have to set one up (there are lots of simple, free ones).

Comment: Take a look at relative paths see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#h-5.1.2). If your images is in the same directory as the script file you could for example just do `var iconurl = iconCode + ".png";` If your setup would have a main directory with one sub directory script and another images the path might look something like `var iconurl = "../images/" + iconCode + ".png";`

Comment: Thanks @Honkalonkalooooohhh! That works for me!